# X is declared but its value is never read. Though I have used the variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using some properties in my Angular component, but I'm getting the following warnings in VSCode:

```
'_id' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
(property) ItemEditComponent._id: number | undefined

'_isModeEdit' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
(property) ItemEditComponent._isModeEdit: boolean
```

This is also my component:

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-edit',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './item-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-edit.component.scss'],
})
export class ItemEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  private _routeParamsSub: Subscription = new Subscription();

  private _id: number | undefined = undefined;  // I'm getting the warning for this variable!
  private _isModeEdit = false;                  // And this one!

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._routeParamsSub = this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this._initPage(+params['id']);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._routeParamsSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  _initPage(id: number | undefined) {
    if (!id) return;
    this._id = id;
    this._isModeEdit = true;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm actually using the variables! Any ideas why I'm seeing such warnings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `As you can see, I'm actually using the variables!` Where exactly?

Comment: Yes, I got it :) I was just writing the component and I was not done with it yet... So yea, I actually didn't use them! Lol!

Comment: Btw you don’t need to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *not* using the variables. Assignment isn't using

Comment: @Ali - you are missing the point. it is not TS-specific. If you have in any language `x = 5`, and never use `x`, you would get the same warning. Ask yourself, what do I need these two variables for?

Comment: Oh yes, I actually didn't use the variables yet :D as I was just writing the component and I was not done with it yet! But saw this warning, and thought to just ask to see what is it about. Thanks anyway.